# Using C# how can I get webbrowser element content to a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Im using c# windows application with a webbrowser control to load a website "http://www.betterwaytoweb.com/tag-generator-for-youtube" and I have a richTextBox control that I wish to fill from a web element id "yt-results-body" am not succeeding, This is what i have tried.

---

```
string results = SiteTagGenerator.Document.GetElementById("yt-results-body").GetAttribute("value");
        tagResultsTB.Text = results;
```

---

I found a semi-solution to get the text from the web element value but the textbox doesn't fill up with the text only it displays across my winform application for some reason but I still need to get it into a text box here is the updated code to return the text from the webpage element to a string

---

```
string text = SiteTagGenerator.Document.GetElementById("yt-results-body").InnerText;
        tagResultsTB.Text = text;
```

---

Does anyone know how I can now pass this text string to the textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
SiteTagGenerator.Document.GetElementById("yt-results-body").InnerHtml
```

I have checked your website. The result is stored as an innerHtml, not value. Basically, div doesn't have a value attribute. You can check here for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Comment: Thank you @RoggerTân for your answer my update to the question and your answer both work.

Comment: @HaKDMoDz Great! But I didn't quite understand your second problem. I think you want your textbox to show as multiline. In that case, change your textbox's ScrollBars property to "vertical", WordWrap and Multiline to "true".

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @RoggerTân I sorted out the last part of the problem it was a silly mistake sending the text to the wrong control on my form :/ thanks Question Answered

Comment: Glad I could help =]]